# pre commit hooks in python specific CI CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We have lot of python code residing in local git repository. Having installed gitlab locally, need to implement CI/CD pipeline. Need is to ensure, that all code is sanitized before being pushed to remote git repository. pre commit hooks that come by default with git, should help in doing so. Question is will it help to integrate git hooks with CI / CD pipeline? How ?

Answer (score 1):

That hook is a [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks).

While CI/CD is done on the server side. Which means the hook itself is not integrated, but the script/command used by that hook can be reused in a gateway pipeline (on a [runner configured to run Python](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml)).
(See also those [CICD pipelines examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/))

- you push your topic/feature branch
- the gateway pipeline is triggered (by the push event)

  - if it passes, it merges in turn your code to an integration branch (like development)
  - if it does not pass, your code does not end up on the dev branch, forcing you to fix whatever issue was highlighted by the gateway pipeline execution.

---

You also have [Code Quality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html) reports, to analyze how your improvements are impacting your code’s quality.